# PHPMailer SMTP localhost, certificate error

Tags: php, email, ssl, certificate, phpmailer

We use PHPMailer. The server is configured to use the local SMTP. 
So, the general PHPMailer commando looks like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'info@localdomain.com';
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->IsSMTP();
...
```

Since PHP5.6, this doesn't work anymore, because the certificate does not match. We get the following error:

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate
>   CN='*.thisvps.com' did not match expected CN='localhost' in /ho...PHPMailer_latest/class.smtp.php

I can suppress this error using:

```
$this->smtpConnect([
   'ssl' => [
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false,
       'allow_self_signed' => true
   ]
]);
```

But, is that the correct way to go? I'm not a big fan of suppressing errors;).
Or maybe there is an error in our configuration?

Version info:
PHP 5.6.30,
PHPMailer: 5.2.21

Any suggestion are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It's odd that you're getting that cert from the server if it's not something you have configured. It could be down to your ISP redirecting your traffic, though I wouldn't expect that to affect localhost.

You can turn off encryption altogether (it's safe to localhost as there's no external network traffic) with `$mail->SMTPSecure = false;`, though you may need to also set `$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;` to prevent it being re-enabled automatically if your server advertises `STARTTLS`.

Alternatively, this host presumably has a hostname in the `thisvps.com` domain that you could use, and then the name would match the cert.

Comment: For the hostname (x.thisvps.nl) i have installed a certificate for the SMTP connection, because before that, the error was that there was no certificate installed at all. Looking at the debug info of PHPmailer, it looks like it is connection to x.thisvps.nl (possible by translating localhost to hostname or something). But no luck.. Thanks for your answer! I will disable the SMTP secure for now, because it's save.